# Dynamic grouping mutiple columns aggregation using Dynamic Linq

Tags: linq

```
using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;


public class Program
{

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    // some sample data   

    List<AggregateGrouping> lstgrpelements = new List<AggregateGrouping>();
    lstgrpelements.Add(new AggregateGrouping{ Name = "Mike", CITY= "Tallahassee", STATE= "FL", value=-3.12M });
    lstgrpelements.Add(new AggregateGrouping{ Name = "Mike", CITY= "Tallahassee", STATE= "FL", value=6.57M });
    lstgrpelements.Add(new AggregateGrouping{ Name = "Steve", CITY= "Tallahassee", STATE= "FL", value=-7.34M });
    lstgrpelements.Add(new AggregateGrouping{ Name = "Steve", CITY= "Tallahassee", STATE= "FL", value=54.64M });
    lstgrpelements.Add(new AggregateGrouping{ Name = "Steve", CITY= "Orlando", STATE= "FL", value=-10.93M });
    lstgrpelements.Add(new AggregateGrouping{ Name = "Steve", CITY= "Orlando", STATE= "FL", value=235.09M });
    lstgrpelements.Add(new AggregateGrouping{ Name = "Mike", CITY= "Orlando", STATE= "NY", value=429.34M });
    lstgrpelements.Add(new AggregateGrouping{ Name = "Mike", CITY= "Orlando", STATE= "NY", value=-67.12M });

// Converts to list to iEnumrable.
IEnumerable<AggregateGrouping> enumgrpelements = lstgrpelements;
 }
}



Public Class AggregateGrouping
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string CITY{ get; set; }
 public string STATE{ get; set; }
 public decimal value{ get; set; }
```

}

How to have IEnumerable to groupby (CITY AND STATE) dynamic data aggregation (on Values) using Dynamic Linq. CITY AND STATE columns are examples but there can be grouping on multiple columns dynamic at run time. I would like the output as aggregate on Values field.

Thanks, Ashutosh.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use my product [AdaptiveLINQ](http://www.adaptivelinq.com). Define a *cube* by specifying dimensions and measures expressions and combine the use of `QueryByCube` and `Select` to compute aggregated values.